# How to validate type 'java.lang.Boolean' in Spring boot with annotation

Tags: spring-data

I have a PUT method like this:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v3/config/{someId}",produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
ResponseEntity<String> updateConfig(@ApiParam(value = "someId",required=true) @PathVariable("someId") String someId,@Valid @RequestBody Config body) throws Exception;`

and the class Config looks like this:

```
@Validated
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Config {

@JsonProperty("boo")
private boolean boo;

public boolean isBoo() {
    return boo;
}

public void setBoo(boolean boo) {
    this.boo = boo;
}
}
```

;
And If client send the request like this way:

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 
'{  
 "boo": 123 \ 
}'  'https://localhost/api/v3/config/1'
```

Spring will convert int 123 into boolean value = true, so I will get boo=true;
How do I validate this case?

Comment: Who is converting 11 to boolean?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I believe It is spring

Comment: so please show some code

Comment: Your request  payload was wrong. If your response body contains Boolean type then you send Boolean. That is correct format of API request.